# S transform and its implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i have signal that is given by  following formula

```
fs=100; % sampling frequency
ts=1/fs;
t=(0:ts:2.93);  % time vector 
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t).*(t<1)+20*cos(2*pi*23.3*t).*(t<1)+24*sin(2*pi*22.6*t).*(t<1)+21*sin(2*pi*23.6*t).*(t>=1)+26*cos(2*pi*21*t).*(t>=1)+21*sin(2*pi*23.9*t).*(t>=1);
z=x+10*randn(size(t));
z=z';
plot(t',z);
```

i know that s-transform is calculated in matlab  as follow

[image]

but problem is that how to define  given function below?   for instance symbol that is given in exponential term?  generally i guess that i should multiply signal by window and then take absolute value of  Fourier transform  ,but  main difficult is in  window function defining, so please help me how can i define Gaussian window in this case? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look over this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45848-stockwell-transform--s-transform- ?

Comment: how can i use then  given result for frequency content  finding?